# Symfony2のFOSUserBundleで、fos_user_registration(登録フォーム)にオリジナルのフォーム及びそこから入力された情報を格納するORM上のカラムを生成したい

Tags: symfony2

Symfony 2.6と、[FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)を使い、ユーザー登録が必要なサイトを作ろうとしています。
デフォルトで用意されているフィールド以外に、String型のカスタムフィールドを持った上でカスタムバリデーションを設定し、指定のDB上のカラムへとORM経由で入力したいと考えました。

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md
上記、FOSUserBundleの公式ドキュメントに書いてある通り、src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php で FOS\UserBundle\Model\User をオーバーライドする方法でこの機能を実装しようと試みました。

結果として、フォームとバリデーションに関しては正常に動作するようになりました。
しかし、そこから入力された値が入るはずのカラムが生成されません。
上記公式ドキュメントの指示通りにString型のカスタムフィールドを実装した後、[このサイト](http://old.ganchiku.com/blog/2012/05/1175.html)を参考に

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme
```

> [以下出力]
>   Generating entities for namespace "Acme"
>   backing up User.php to User.php~
>   generating Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User

でアクセサを作成し、

```
php console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

でスキーマをアップデートし、この時点でカスタムフィールドを格納するカラムがDB上に生成されるはずでした。
しかし、schema:updateでは以下のメッセージが出力されるのみで、カラムについても追加はされておりませんでした。

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

結果として、今もバリデーションのみうまく動作しているフォームが/register/にあるのみで、そこに値を入れても保存されず素通りしてしまいます。
この場合、どうすればカスタムフィールドの値が保存されるようになりますでしょうか。

Comment: src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.phpクラスですが、 https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md このページの中ほどにあるコードのように、クラスのアノテーション（@ORM\Entity等）は付けられているでしょうか？

Comment: @HidenoriGOTO ありがとうございます。アノテーションは付けているはずですが、抜けがあるかもしれません。コードのほうを添付させていただきます。https://gist.github.com/mekkoo/313f6964e1809cc43237

Comment: 手元で確認したところ、acme_userテーブルにsitetitleカラムはできました。例えば、一度ＤＢ側のacme_userテーブルを削除してからdoctrine:schema:updateしてみるなど等では、何か状況が変わるでしょうか。